# Protractor - Get text from table

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

I have list of "cases" in a table, where I need to find specific one just by NAME and click on it.

My HTML looks like:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="case in cases | orderBy:order:order_reverse" class="middle ng-scope odd readonly" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class="{readonly: !caseManager.isWritable(case)}">
                    <td>
                        <span ax-sharing-circle="SHARED_WITH_PARTNER" class="ng-isolate-scope"><span class="icon sharing-circle sharing-circle-left" title="Sdílený"></span></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="case-table-claim-number fix-v-align">
                        <a ui-sref="case.general({caseId: case.caseId})" class="ng-binding" href="#/case/0a0b1c2a-94b4-444c-a2b8-c62cbd3532ae/general">20150629-165000-65</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="case-table-claim-number fix-v-align ng-binding"></td>
                    <td class="case-table-claim-number fix-v-align ng-binding"></td>
                    <td class="case-table-make fix-v-align ng-binding"></td>
                    <td class="case-table-make fix-v-align ng-binding"></td>
                    <td class="case-table-status fix-v-align ng-binding">
                        29.6.2015
                    </td>
                    <td class="case-table-status fix-v-align ng-binding"></td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" ng-class="{
                                'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up': hasOverview(case.caseId),
                                'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down': !hasOverview(case.caseId),
                              }" ng-click="toggleOverview(case.caseId)"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

In example above you can find string `20150629-165000-65` which is name of the case.

I try to write something like this:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('a', global.caseNumber)).click();
```

which should find element and click on it, instead of that it throw error:

> No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText("a", "20150629-165000-65")

Can someone advise me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a relevant `by.linkText()` locator that should fit the use case:

```
var link = element(by.linkText(global.caseNumber));
```

---

If it still doesn't find the desired element, try adding a wait:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(link), 5000);
```

Comment: Correct as always :) Thanks (will mark it as soon as it will be possible)